# Know lifespan of a creature

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Is there anything in 3.5 that works like the Shinigami Eyes in Death note?
I want to see when someone's time is up, when someone is supposed to die, to know when someone is dying etc
Is this possible in 3.5?

Answer (score 3):

The first-level cleric spell Deathwatch lets you identify if people have three or fewer hit points.

A really good Heal check might allow you to notice when someone is unhealthy. This doesn't seem to be officially supported but it's a very common house rule.

The problem with a general purpose "know when someone is about to die" power is that many deaths happen because someone takes an unexpected critical hit for 50 damage, and there's no way to know that's coming before the die roll.

(And many of the rest of the deaths are because the adventurers decide to kill someone, and there's no power that can tell you that decision will happen before you make it.)

A friend of mine is running a game where one of the players has death sight, and part of the plot involves her watching as all her friends get doomed to die by some unknown source, and she has to find a way to avert it. But that's not D&D and there aren't any rules for it -- it was done by cooperation with the DM.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a spell in Wizards magazine, no such spell exists in 3.5 that does this. You can modify 'wish' to do this, or use 'commune' and see if your deity knows. Otherwise, 'status' might help you if you're in combat, but the target must be willing.